# Сортировка значений словаря при помощи sorted()

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, словари, dict

Задача: отсортировать значения словаря.

Наткнулся на непонятную конструкцию: key=my_dict.get

Почему в данном случае происходит сортировка, если get-это метод класса dict и у него есть обязательный аргумент? 
Все остальное - понятно.

```py
result = sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)[:3]
```

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Параметр `key` в функции [sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) - **функция**, которая вызывается для каждого элемента из `iterable`.

Таким образом мы можем сортировать сложные объекты, указывая атрибуты или элементы вложенных списков / массивов.

---

Пример:

```
In [21]: my_dict = {"b": 100, "c": 10, "a": 50}

In [22]: sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)
Out[22]: ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

можно переписать более понятным, но менее элегантным способом:

```
In [23]: sorted(my_dict, key=lambda x: my_dict.get(x), reverse=True)
Out[23]: ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: Все максимально ясно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве аргумента `key` функции `sorted` передаётся **имя** функции, которая из сложного составляющего сортируемого возвращает значение, по которому необходимо произвести сортировку.

[Здесь](http://python-3.ru/page/sorted) можно прочитать подробнее.

Также советую ознакомиться с [официальной документацией](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) на эту тему.

Comment: *выделяет параметр* скорее "возвращает значение". Оно может определяться не по одному параметру

Comment: @splash58 Да, так лучше, спасибо. Поправил.